# Swift keep navigation between modal and push segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue

My app starts out with a tableView that has a navigation bar.

If I press on the search icon in the navigation bar a new segue will be displayed as "Present modally". I need to keep it as "Present modally" since I am using a special library in order to get a custom segue animation.

Anyways, from this 2nd VC I have another segue that is set as "Show" in order to display another tableView where you can select some filters.
When you get too this VC there is on back button.

How can I implement a back button between VC2 - VC3?

**Edit:**

Between VC2 and VC3 I have placed a Navigation Controller and this seem to work. But is this the way to do it?

This means that I have two Navigation Controllers in my story board:

**Navigation Controller** > **VC1** (Present modally segue)> **VC2** > **Navigation Controller** (root vc)> **VC3**

Answer (score 0):

If you embed the second view controller in a navigation controller, you should get the Back button after pushing the third view controller. This means that you will modally present the navigation controller instead of the second view controller, but the second view controller will be the root of the navigation controller.